# display the top 2 salaries from emlpoyee table using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a requirement to fetch the top 2 salaries from employee table
iam using below query but getting error 
please can anyone help?

```
SELECT iICompanyID,
       iIsequence
FROM employee
WHERE dIAmount IN (SELECT MAX(dIAmount)FROM employee)
   OR dIAmount IN ((SELECT MAX(diamount)
                    FROM employee
                    WHERE diamount IN (SELECT dIAmount
                                       FROM employee
                                       WHERE dIAmount NOT IN (SELECT MAX(diamount)FROM employee)
                                      )
```

Comment: This is why **good** use of whitespace is important. Now that I've formatted your query it should be very evident what is wrong with it (apart from the insane amount of nested `SELECT` statements). Also, when posting in regards to an error, it's important to include the error. The volunteers here can't run your SQL without sample data, nor can they see your screen

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function to find the employees sorted by salary. The following should return top 2 (possibly more if there are ties) employees by salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dIAmount DESC) AS rnk
    FROM employee
) x
WHERE rnk <= 2
```

Comment: If you want to know more about `DENSE_RANK`, read up on it [here...](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/live/docs/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `DISTINCT TOP(2)` with `ORDER BY diamount DESC` as below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE dIAmount IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) dIAmount 
        FROM employee 
        ORDER BY dIAmount DESC
    )
```

Or you can use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE IN` condition as below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) dIAmount AS dIAmount
        FROM employee 
        ORDER BY dIAmount DESC
) M ON E.dIAmount = M.dIAmount
```